# Como bloquear um usuário por algumas horas

Tags: android, parse.com

Em minha aplicação Android, nós temos uma política de uso do aplicativo e caso algumas regras sejam violadas pelo usuário o cadastro dele deverá ser suspenso por algumas horas.
Eu utilizo o Parse.com como framework de back-end, o problema para mim não é criar a Flag que o cadastro dele está bloqueado, é reagendar o desbloqueio desse cadastro, como posso fazer?

Comment: talvez esse dois links possam lhe ajudar, e você pode adaptar o bloqueio e desbloqueio verificando uma flag atráves das suas regras de negócio, https://parse.com/questions/is-there-a-way-to-block-a-particular-user-or-email-address  e  https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Cloud.html#methods_run

Comment: Não servem não...  estou com mais dificuldade se devo na parte do cliente usar um alarm mananger para desbloquea-lo ou devo usar outro modo...